# Angular language service not working ,new version

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-language-service

I checked the Angular package.json files, but the current version is showing there. When I check the Angular language extension, it shows 15.2 which is not the current version. it happened after updating [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIoio.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5hPc.png)
I looked at all angular language settings[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/houqa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess visual studio code did not accept the update because the version is old. I deleted and re-downloaded it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you see the reviews next to it? Not quite unwarranted. It's notoriously bad at times. Your only hope is, to go back and install older versions of the language service. There are many esoteric suggestions in comments, blogs, and so forth, but they never were the solution.
[image]

After you select that, try to pick a corresponding version to your currently running Angular version and try out different versions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks your feedback but when I was try this way , I can't see this section. [See](https://ibb.co/DVSjsK0)

Comment: Looks to me like you don't have the newest version then. Did you try updating the LS? You could try uninstalling it and installing it fresh again.

Comment: I've tried. I deleted and reinstalled

Comment: This worked for me. Were using angular 12. Thanks.